# Preserve Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have Jenkins set up to run concurrent builds, so I end up with workspace, workspace@2, workspace@3, etc. If Jenkins thinks the build is finished, a new build will overwrite the workspace. Is there a way of occasionally preventing that? E.g. Don't overwrite workspace@3 until I say.
We have various scenarios where this would be very useful.

Answer (score 10):

You could simply archive the complete workspace at the end of a build. It would then get deleted when the job is deleted.

To do this:

- Add post-build action -> "Archive the artifacts"
- Enter `**` as "Files to archive"

If you want to make that configurable per run, you could create a build parameter:

- (enable "This is a parametrized build" if not yet enabled)
- add parameter of type "Choice Parameter" and name it `ARCHIVE`
- with choices being `<blank line>` and `**` (literally, put a blank first line, then second line is exactly `**`. No quotes)
- use `${ARCHIVE}` as "Files to archive" in "Advanced" setting of "Archive the Artifacts" action
- enable checkbox "Do not fail build if archiving returns nothing"

Comment: Hi, this could work for me, but the solution provided by zloj is better for my situation, as my workspaces use up a lot of diskspace and I only need this feature occasionally.

Comment: Hi @tarantoga - will the archive still exist after the Build is deleted? Example: My job is set up to delete build older than 10 days. I would like it to also delete the archived files produced by those deleted builds.

Comment: Hello @Hervian - yes, files archived by a build are deleted when the build is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the agent in the hole pipeline, so the jenkins will use only the "workspace" dir.

For example (this is a NOT WORKING example):

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    environment {
        // Environment variables
    }    
    stages {
        stage('Clear dir') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
        stage('Make checkout') {
            agent any    // **THIS IS WRONG!!!!** 
            steps {
                echo 'Making checkout'
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

In the previous example, the "agent any" inside the stage will allow jenkins to create a "workspace@2" folder.

To prevent this, leave the agent only in the pipeline.
Correct example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any   // This is right! leave only this mention of agent 
    environment {
        // Environment variables
    }    
    stages {
        stage('Clear dir') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
        stage('Make checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Making checkout'
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins stores current workspace as an environment `${WORKSPACE}` variable.
You can rename it at any moment of the job as long as you also set the renamed **absolute** directory path to `${WORKSPACE}` variable within the build. When to do that is your choice now.

Another option is to schedule a downstream job and pass the `${WORKSPACE}` to that job as parameter so that you can rename it.

Comment: Ok, thanks - this seems like it will work best for me, except I can't work out where to set the WORKSPACE at the very start of the job (before SCM checkout).

Comment: There is plugin called "Pre SCM BuildStep", it says "This plugin allows build steps to be performed before the SCM step performs an action.".

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes a bit late and probably not totally correct answer to your question, but this is the first ticket which I found when searching solution for my problem.

I had problem with having two folders JobName_XXXX and JobName_XXXX@2. 
At first my build worked well and I added parallel build for another Jenkins node. After I removed the parallel build, I encountered problem with build. It did not anymore work.
I used blueocean's pipeline editor to create Jenkinsfile. By removing the parallel build I set "agent: any" to each step. It caused jenkins to reset scm inside the step. So I could not use previous steps' build results and build crashed.
**Solution was to remove "agent: any" from steps/stages**. It is ok to have agent: any; directly inside the pipeline. With pipeline editor you cant remove those "agent: any" things -- at least not now? So edit Jenkinsfile manually.