# how to keep the workspace of a jenkins build without stash/unstash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, workspace

I have separated a build in multiple stages that are all wrapped in their own node block.
It's intended that the builds can be paused at those stages if there's heavy activity on the jenkins instance, but they should continue when executors are available.

```
stage('one'){
   node { ... }
}
// free up the executor if many other builds are running
stage('two'){
   node { ... }
}
```

This approach works well together with [milestone](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-milestone-step/)s and [lock](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/)s to be able to cancel builds that have been waiting too long.

Now our problem is, that with multiple node blocks the documentation says you have to [stash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)/[unstash](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstash-restore-files-previously-stashed) files to keep the results that have been produced in the last workspace. Now our workspace contains many files that take like 5 to 10 minutes to stash/unstash which kills every other performance gain.

Is there a way to effectively reserve the last workspace until a build is finished. Just staying on the same node does not help as a concurrently started build can be assigned to the same workspace if the older build is just paused

```
def nodeName
stage('one'){
   node {
       nodeName = "${NODE_NAME}"
   }
}
stage('two'){
   node(nodeName) { 
       // this is the same node but another workspace
   }
}
```

The only way I've seen to maybe force the workspace is either the [external workspace manager](https://plugins.jenkins.io/external-workspace-manager) plugin or the [ws](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-ws-code-allocate-workspace) step.
But then I'll lose the default automatic relocation feature for concurrent builds and I need to take care of the cleanup myself as these workspaces are not deleted when a build is removed.

Any ideas how to keep the workspace even after leaving the node?

Comment: I was facing the same problem, and I have already used the ws step as solution. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282783/preserve-jenkins-workspace might be helpful.