# How to restore files after checkpoint in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am trying to add checkpoint in my Jenkins stage.
Since all of the stages runs inside on single node, I cannot put it outside the node .
I have used checkpoint before starting a particular approval stage , so when job fails and i retry the job from the failed stage , it picks up the variable but it doesn't restore the files .
Is there any way i can restore all the files from previous workspace and use it in the new one.

Or is there any way to restore those files? Kindly help

Comment: A good and a reliable option would be to preserve the workspace..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282783/preserve-jenkins-workspace

Comment: I didn't get how to do that.. I'm using pipeline as code .